# FAILED (remote: unknown command) fastboot oem unlock in adb

Tags: android, adb, bootloader, android-debug, fastboot

I tried everything, I have a **SAMSUNG GALAXY A02s**. I want to **unlock the bootloader of my device**.

I have enabled *OEM unlocking*
I have enabled *USB debugging*
^^ ---> developer options..

I also deleted the two adb key files in **C:\users\{USER}\.android**

STILL I can't unlock my bootloader via fastboot...

---

- I did: **fastboot OEM unlock** --> FAILED
- I did: **fastboot oem unlock** --> FAILED
- I did: **fastboot flashing unlock** --> FAILED
- I did: **fasboot oem unlock {SERIAL NUMBER/DEVICE NAME}** --> FAILED
- I did: **fastboot oem unlock critical** --> FAILED
- I did: **fastboot oem unlock_critical** --> FAILED

I also changed my drivers lots of times. So the drivers are fine.

Everytime I do **fastboot oem unlock** . it gives me::::::
*ERROR*: **FAILED (remote: unknown command)**

Please someone help me.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187560/fastboot-commands-dont-work-at-all-on-my-samsung-phone

Answer (score 0):

Yoh, in order to unlock oem, go to download mode on your samsung phone. There should be 3 option. One for installing custom room, the other for boot unlocker and the other to cancel downmode. Just try it that way.